# dynamic multidimensional array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I am not sure whether or not this has been answered before, but this question is really specific. I am attempting to code a dungeon generator in c#, and I want the size of the array to be dynamic, and it to display in the console as a grid, per the size inputted. I got the array to be dynamic, and it can display every index in a grid form, but I can't figure out how to make the amount of indexes in a row dynamic. Here's what I have so far:

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num;
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int x = num;
        int y = num;
        int i = x - 1;
        int j = y - 1;
        int[,] dungeon = new int[x,y];

        for(int z = 0; z <= i; z++)
        {
            int a = 0;
            for( a = 0; a <= j; a++)
              {
                  dungeon[a,z] = rand.Next(0,2);
              }

            }
            for (int h = 0; h <= i; h++) 
            {
                if (h == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("#-#-#-#-#");
                }
            Console.WriteLine("|" + dungeon[h,0] + "|" + dungeon[h,1] + "|" + dungeon[h,2] + "|" + dungeon[h,3] + "|");
            Console.WriteLine("#-#-#-#-#");
```

Excuse the messiness. It isn't quite finished yet.

Comment: Are you limited to using an array for some reason?  Other wise generic ICollection<T> types are much easier to work with (like a [List<int>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

Comment: No, not limited to using only arrays. I'm just new to c#.

Answer (score 1):

Well, currently the grid is always an exact square. Because you use the same value for both dimensions. Do you just want to use a separate value for each dimension?  If so, you need another value from the input.  You can do that the same way you already do.  For example:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

A couple things to note:

1. You don't need your `num` variable, all you do is immediately assign it to another variable and then never use `num` again.  Just use your intended variable(s) in the first place.
2. As an academic exercise, take a look at `int.TryParse()` and examples of how to use it.  Currently if anything other than an integer is input, the application will crash.  With `int.TryParse()` you can handle that error condition.
3. Also as an academic exercise, take a look at using a nested list instead of a 2-dimensional array.  Something like `List<List<int>>`.  In some ways it'll look more verbose (re: messy), in other ways it'll be more useful.  Continuing from there, try to encapsulate the entire data structure into a custom object (`Grid` or `Board` seem like reasonable names).  That would allow you to put any messy stuff inside a class and then the game logic can cleanly interact with that class.

Comment: No, I wanted the dimensions to be the same. As for the list, I'll try that out.

Comment: @MichaelAlexander: Then what exactly are you asking?  If you got the number of rows to be dynamic, and you want the number of columns to equal the number of rows, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the size of the array to be dynamic

So if you have no restriction on Generic Collections, I would highly recommend using a List<>.  Ignoring better ways of scrubbing user input, your code using lists could look like the following.  Since we're using a Object oriented language, it's best to create objects that represent our needs (a cell, a grid, etc).  Then create properties or methods that represent things we need form those objects, (rows, columns, values).

So I'm going to throw you right into the deep end, but here are references for what i'm using.

[Delegates, Anonymous Methods, and Lambda Expressions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47887/C-Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressio). - A very good article about all the different statements/abstractions of the same thing.

[Lambda expressions () =>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)  - Microsoft Docs.

[Lambda expressions in a Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-use-lambda-expressions-in-a-query) - How to Query lists using Linq Methods with Lambda Expressions.

[Func(TResult)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) - Basically another Delegate.. does C# have enough of these now?

[Generic Classes; MyClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) - The power of Generics!

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E3qfbQ).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        int num;
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Func<int> valueGenerator = () => { return rand.Next(0,2); };
        var dungeon = new Grid<int>(num, num, valueGenerator);

        foreach(var row in dungeon.Rows)
        {
            // First() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx
            if (row.First().Row == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("#-#-#-#-#");
            }
            // ToArray() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx
            var rowValues = row.Select(r => r.Value.ToString()).ToArray();

            // string.Join() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx
            var rowDisplay = string.Join("|", rowValues);

            // $ ie Interpolated Strings - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings
            Console.WriteLine($"|{rowDisplay}|");
            Console.WriteLine("#-#-#-#-#"); 
        }
    }

    public class Grid<T>
    {
        private int _numberOfRows;
        private int _numberOfColumns;

        // List<> - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx
        private List<Cell<T>> _cells;

        public Grid(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)
        {
            if (numberOfRows == 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberOfRows must be greater than zero.");
            if (numberOfColumns == 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberOfColumns must be greater than zero.");

            _numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
            _numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;

            // Enumerable.Range - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx
            _cells = Enumerable.Range(0, _numberOfRows)
                // Select - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx
                .Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, _numberOfColumns)
                        .Select(c => new Cell<T>
                                {
                                    Row = r,
                                    Col = c
                                })
                        // ToList() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx
                        .ToList())
                // - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx
                .SelectMany(c => c)
                .ToList();
        }

        public Grid(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns, Func<T> valueGenerator)
        {
            if (numberOfRows == 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberOfRows must be greater than zero.");
            if (numberOfColumns == 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberOfColumns must be greater than zero.");

            _numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
            _numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;

            _cells = Enumerable.Range(0, _numberOfRows)
                .Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, _numberOfColumns)
                        .Select(c => new Cell<T>
                                {
                                    Row = r,
                                    Col = c,
                                    Value = valueGenerator()
                                })
                        .ToList())
                .SelectMany(c => c)
                .ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<ICell<T>> Cells
        {
            get
            {
                return _cells;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ICell<T>>> Rows
        {
            get
            {           
                return _cells.GroupBy(c => c.Row)
                    .Select(gs => gs.OrderBy(g => g.Col).ToList())
                    .ToList();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ICell<T>>> Columns
        {
            get
            {
                return _cells.GroupBy(c => c.Col)
                    .Select(gs => gs.OrderBy(g => g.Row).ToList())
                    .ToList();
            }
        }

        // We expose the Interface because we don't want anyone outside grid modifying
        // Row or Col
        public interface ICell<T>
        {
            int Row { get; }
            int Col { get; }
            T Value { get; set; }
        }

        private class Cell<T> : ICell<T>
        {
            public T Value { get; set; }
            public int Row { get; set; }
            public int Col { get; set; }
        }


    }

}
```

Output (well the 0s and 1s are random so...)

> 4

```
#-#-#-#-#
|0|0|0|1|
#-#-#-#-#
|1|0|0|1|
#-#-#-#-#
|0|0|1|0|
#-#-#-#-#
|0|1|1|0|
#-#-#-#-#
```

After all of this you might be asking yourself, why use a generic class Grid?  Well I doubt that the only thing you want to store in a Cell is an int.  Maybe you want to store a full object that represents all sorts of things...

[int Replaced with DungeonCell<>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nlLfkX)

Comment: Yes. The end goal is to get objects in the cells. What I was trying to do was code something basic that could randomly generate rooms. (1 is a room, 0 isn't). Once that was working, (and by then, hopefully I would have an actual IDE and not Sololearn) I would work on making them objects.